Extracting tables through puppeeteer
I am working on my university project. I want to extract data from my university LMS; I cracked the login authentication, and now I want to extract HTML of my subjects attendance and sessional marks data through Puppeeteer.
Here is the HTML and screenshot of the course details page:

<table class="table table-hover">
  <tbody><tr>
    <th>Course Code</th>
    <th>Course Name</th>
    <th>Credit Hours</th>
    <th>Sections</th>
    <th></th>
   
  </tr>
   
      <tr>
    <td>PHYS-1121</td>
    <td>Applied Physics</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>BS-COSC-1C</td>
    <td>
        <button onclick="viewAttendance('025753a46b93f77d6769db8d3e54c2a8')" class="btn btn-primary">Attendance</button>
        <button onclick="viewSessionalMarks('025753a46b93f77d6769db8d3e54c2a8')" class="btn btn-success">Sessional Marks</button>
    </td>
    
  </tr>
   
      <tr>
    <td>COSC-1101</td>
    <td>Programming Fundamentals</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>BS-COSC-1C</td>
    <td>
        <button onclick="viewAttendance('2c696da8660c3eb67c12da6c5d0e5652')" class="btn btn-primary">Attendance</button>
        <button onclick="viewSessionalMarks('2c696da8660c3eb67c12da6c5d0e5652')" class="btn btn-success">Sessional Marks</button>
    </td>
    
  </tr>
   
      <tr>
    <td>COSC-1105</td>
    <td>Introduction to ICT</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>BS-COSC-1C</td>
    <td>
        <button onclick="viewAttendance('a590668ce864603dcf088ca277e3678a')" class="btn btn-primary">Attendance</button>
        <button onclick="viewSessionalMarks('a590668ce864603dcf088ca277e3678a')" class="btn btn-success">Sessional Marks</button>
    </td>
    
  </tr>
   
      <tr>
    <td>COSC-1201</td>
    <td>Programming Fundamentals-Lab</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>BS-COSC-1C</td>
    <td>
        <button onclick="viewAttendance('dd1f0e8af64c6b8243c7b62a4ef847d4')" class="btn btn-primary">Attendance</button>
        <button onclick="viewSessionalMarks('dd1f0e8af64c6b8243c7b62a4ef847d4')" class="btn btn-success">Sessional Marks</button>
    </td>
    
  </tr>
   
      <tr>
    <td>COSC-1205</td>
    <td>Introduction to ICT-Lab</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>BS-COSC-1C</td>
    <td>
        <button onclick="viewAttendance('76b8353abb341d44f4cfe9a722590ead')" class="btn btn-primary">Attendance</button>
        <button onclick="viewSessionalMarks('76b8353abb341d44f4cfe9a722590ead')" class="btn btn-success">Sessional Marks</button>
    </td>
    
  </tr>
   
      <tr>
    <td>MATH-1106</td>
    <td>Quantitative Reasoning-I</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>BS-COSC-1D,BS-COSC-1C</td>
    <td>
        <button onclick="viewAttendance('8495e1a23aaa4f78a8a5de93a158b798')" class="btn btn-primary">Attendance</button>
        <button onclick="viewSessionalMarks('8495e1a23aaa4f78a8a5de93a158b798')" class="btn btn-success">Sessional Marks</button>
    </td>
    
  </tr>
   
      <tr>
    <td>ISLS-1128</td>
    <td>Islamic Studies</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>BS-COSC-1C</td>
    <td>
        <button onclick="viewAttendance('a2b3fa9fc5e430de2302286b1ddd8f81')" class="btn btn-primary">Attendance</button>
        <button onclick="viewSessionalMarks('a2b3fa9fc5e430de2302286b1ddd8f81')" class="btn btn-success">Sessional Marks</button>
    </td>
    
  </tr>
   
      <tr>
    <td>MATH-1124</td>
    <td>Basic Mathematics</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>BS-COSC-1B,BS-COSC-1A,BS-COSC-1D,BS-COSC-1C</td>
    <td>
        <button onclick="viewAttendance('6633270eae099fb6c1a6354297f66fd0')" class="btn btn-primary">Attendance</button>
        <button onclick="viewSessionalMarks('6633270eae099fb6c1a6354297f66fd0')" class="btn btn-success">Sessional Marks</button>
    </td>
    
  </tr>
   
</tbody></table>


I want to get the course details like the course code, course name, credit hours, and section, and after all of that, click on the attendance button; a popup will appear; get the html code inside that; close the popup; click on the sessional marks button; a popup will show; get all the html code inside that; close the popup. This process repeats for all courses.
I tried to map through all courses, but it gives the wrong response.
    if (targetFrame) {
      await targetFrame.click('.fa.fa-book');
      await targetFrame.waitForSelector('tbody');

      const data = await targetFrame.evaluate(async () => {
        const rows = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('tbody tr')).slice(1);
        console.log('33333333',rows)
        return Promise.all(rows.map(async row => {
          const cells = row.querySelectorAll('td');
          const rowsData = {
            courseCode: cells[0]?.innerText.trim(),
            courseName: cells[1]?.innerText.trim(),
            creditHours: cells[2]?.innerText.trim(),
            sections: cells[3]?.innerText.trim(),
          };
      
          const buttons = cells[4]?.querySelectorAll('button');
          if (buttons) {
            buttons[0].click();
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500));
            const attendancePopup = document.querySelector('#courseAttendaceModel');
            const secondTable = attendancePopup?.querySelectorAll('table')[1];
            
            if (secondTable) {
              const attendanceRows = Array.from(secondTable.querySelectorAll('tr')).slice(1);
              rowsData.attendance = attendanceRows.map(attendanceRow => {
                const attendanceTds = attendanceRow.querySelectorAll('td');
                return {
                  td2: attendanceTds[2]?.innerText.trim() || 'No data',
                  td3: attendanceTds[3]?.innerText.trim() || 'No data',
                  td5: attendanceTds[5]?.innerText.trim() || 'No data',
                };
              });
            } else {
              rowsData.attendance = 'No attendance data';
            }
      
            const closeButton = attendancePopup?.querySelector('.btn.btn-default');
            if (closeButton) {
              closeButton.click();
              await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500)); // Adjust delay to ensure popup closes
            }
          }
          return rowsData;
        }
      ));
      });
      console.log('enrollmentData', JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    }


After that, I tried to get only one course detail first, but it gave empty string.
    const data = await targetFrame.evaluate(() => {
      const rows = document.querySelectorAll('tbody tr:nth-child(2) td');
    
      return {
        courseCode: rows[0]?.innerHTML.trim() || '', 
        courseName: rows[1]?.innerHTML.trim() || '',
        creditHours: rows[2]?.innerHTML.trim() || '',
        section: rows[3]?.innerHTML.trim() || '',
      };
    });

    console.log('data: ', data)

I don't know where I am wrong, but my end goal is to get attendance and sessional marks data for all courses.
